# Query a name in large database, optimizations?

Tags: postgresql, performance, query-performance

if you would like to query a name in a very large database, are there some ways to optimize this query? If 1 million names are in the database, and the name has to stay as it was registered (and not with a number for example , myName_108008080 ). I am wondering that in the context of games, when someone is looking for someone else in the database just with his name, the query is quite fast even when the database contains many entries.

Thanks

Comment: "optimize this query"... Sure, where is this query? And what is the table definition? Are you able to change the definition of the database? And finally, which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: It's difficult to answer your question without having more information. Can you post your query? You can change the name of the objects as long as it maintains the integrity of the query.

Comment: I have no special query for now except a simple Select with a WHERE clause of name = myName, this is why I was wondering the effect on a 'large' db (at least I thought it was large!) I will use postgreSQL, I thought I could gather the names by their first letter to reduce the cost of the query, but except that I haven't more ideas.

Comment: @PaulWright - you seem to have a case of premature optimization. Do not design your application trying to guess where the database performance bottleneck might be, because it will be elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand the feeling that 1mil+ rows is "Very Large", however you should understand that to a lot of database people you aren't getting into a large table until you have 10s-100s of millions of rows.  And even then that is middling large.

That being said if I understand what you are asking for you are looking for "indexes".  This is a fairly large concept at times and what index(s) you need really depends on what queries you are running.

I can think of two major categories though that might match what you are looking for.  The first is simple.  You have the name in a column and you want to search the table for everyone with a given name.  For example you are looking for everyone with the name `Ken` and you have a query like this.

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE NameColumn = 'Ken'
```

or you want to get everyone's name that starts with `Ken` and your query looks like this.

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE NameColumn LIKE 'Ken%'
```

In this case a simple index on the NameColumn column of your table will suffice and should give you excellent performance.

If however you want to search for `Bob` and get everyone who has names such as `Bobbie`, `Robert`, `Rob` etc.  Then I believe you want full text indexing.  This is a bit more complicated and has a number of requirements to set up.  If this is what you need then I suggest either having an in house DBA do the work (someone familiar with full text indexing) or do some research yourself.  For example for SQL Server 2012 the BOL entry is [Here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx).

I'm a SQL Server person so my answers are going to bias that way but in all of the RDBMS' that I know of indexing in one form or another is how you improve basic performance of a well written query on a well designed system.  If you need help with the design of the query or system then you will have to provide a great deal more information starting with which RDBMS you are using and your table structure and the query you are trying to optimize.

Comment: Thanks Kenneth, the goal would be to find an entire name in the database. When you say "INDEX", is it a copy of a column put separately in the db? So INDEX is better than a WHERE clause? I will check the timing of a query with the entire name, but I thought it could take a long time with a million rows. Apparently it is not so bad when looking at the comments.

Comment: An index is a part of the table (sort of).  The RDBMS engine uses indexes while determining how to run your query.  Think of an index in an RDBMS as being similar to the index in a book.  If it is an book on databases you might go to the index and look under I then look for In then Ind etc until you find Index .. it will then have a list of pages in the book where you can find information on indexes.  Same thing in a table.